# Is there any advantage of fitting a distribution to the data to calculate the percentile?

Tags: quantiles

Method 1: Calculating the percentiles, e.g. 99 percentile of the data, is straight forward, and the calculation is based on the ordering of the data values.

Method 2: A more complicated way of calculating the percentiles will be first fit a distribution to the data (e.g. if we know the data is normal, we fit a normal distribution, or do a non-parametric Kernel density estimation), and then calculate the inverse cdf to get the 99 percentile of the data.

I am wondering is there any advantage for doing the latter method? My two guesses

- I am thinking inferring the percentiles from the distribution may be more robust as method 1 result is more sensitive to changes in the data?
- We can treat method two result as also a probability of the value occurring, whereas method 1 we can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fitting a distribution to the data first (and then getting the quantiles from the fitted distribution) is a way of *smoothing*, or *regularization*. If you are reasonably confident that your model is reasonable, then that would typically lead to better estimates. Especially if you need estimates out in the tail.

Comment: Thanks - do you know of any reference I can cite that examines this question?